# Unable to login using selenium webdriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium

This is really weird but I suddenly cannot login using selenium. I was able to login with my code just a week ago and then I can't anymore.
Here's the html code from the website:

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="loginUsername" style="width: 100%; font-weight: normal" aria-label="Username">
 <input id="loginUsername" class="form-control" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" autocapitalize="off">
</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label for="loginPassword" style="width: 100%; font-weight: normal" aria-label="Password">
 <input id="loginPassword" class="form-control" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" autocapitalize="off">
</label>
</div>
```

And here is my code before the incident:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loginUsername\"]")).sendKeys("username");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loginPassword\"]")).sendKeys("password");
```

It worked fine before. I even tried changing it up and it looked something like this:

```
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loginUsername\"]")); username.click(); username.clear(); ;username.sendKeys("username");
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loginPassword\"]")); password.click(); password.clear(); ;password.sendKeys("password");
```

I honestly don't know what is wrong with my code and I didn't get any error too. I also tried using "By.name()" or "By.id()" but it still didn't work so I'm really confused. Please help me, thank you!

*edited*
Here's the full version of the code

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
<form action="/login" method="post">
  <div class="form-group title">
  <img src="/img/RA_LOGO_BLUE.png" alt="Risk Assessment System Logo">
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="loginUsername" style="width: 100%; font-weight: normal" aria-label="Username">
  <input id="loginUsername" class="form-control" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" autocapitalize="off">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="loginPassword" style="width: 100%; font-weight: normal" aria-label="Password">
    <input id="loginPassword" class="form-control" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" autocapitalize="off">
  </label>
    </div>
    <input id="loginBtn" class="btn" type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
  <br>
  <div class="text-left">
    <span class="fakeLink" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forgotPasswordModal">Forgot Password?</span><br>
    <span class="fakeLink" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forgotUsernameModal">Forgot Username?</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: At what point does the process get stuck?

Comment: After entering the website url

Comment: You need to be more specific for us to help you. What's the error you get? Does the form get filled?

Comment: The form did not get filled

Comment: From this bit of code, it is hard to tell what is going on. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Posting your question along with adequate details like error from the console would help us to provide you a solution.

Comment: can you post the Url,I shall try the scenario and help you

Answer (score 1):

To send text to the *username* and *password* field you can use the following code block :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='loginUsername']")).sendKeys("username");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='loginPassword']")).sendKeys("password");
```

Comment: try to send us more of HTML, maybe there are more inputs with the same id?

Comment: @NodirNasirov You saw it right. Certainly OP made some manipulation while providing the HTML. Having said that my answer was based on OP's initial code trial when there was no HTML with in the question !!!